# How to stop ng-infinite-scroll after loading complete data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ecmascript-6, nginfinitescroll

Here I am facing some problems while using ng-infinite-scroll. When I am ng-infinite-scroll-distance, it actually doesn't work. Moreover all data has been loaded but ng-infinite-scroll can't be disabled?

```
<div class="row-fluid" infinite-scroll-distance="2" infinite-scroll="self.loadMore(self.friendList)" >
```

How can I make my infinite-scroll disable?

Comment: Post working JsFiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an `infinite-scroll-disabled` property that can be used in your div.

```
<div class="row-fluid" infinite-scroll-distance="2" infinite-scroll="self.loadMore(self.friendList)" infinite-scroll-disabled="infiniteScrollStatus" >
```

where `infiniteScrollStatus` could be a boolean value in your js that is set to true when you detect in your js that all your data has been loaded.

Comment: thanks I wouldn't implement the logic you represent here. It's working.